# Replacement for NSAttributedString initWithFileURL in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I just find out that **initWithFileURL** from **NSAttributedString** was deprecated in iOS 9 and I don't see a proper replacement for it.

Maybe `initWithData`? How can I adapt this code, where I'm loading text from a **rtf** file.

```
_text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL 
                                            options:nil
                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                              error:&error];
```

**EDIT:**

What i'm doing now is this:

```
- (void)loadText
{
  NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:self.rtfFile withExtension:nil];
  NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[fileURL path]];

  NSError *error = nil;

_text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                                          options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType}
                               documentAttributes:nil
                                            error:&error];

}
```

But `_text` gets nil. I checked `data` and is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function which is available in iOS 9 to Initialize NSAttribiuted String from a NSURL

```
- (instancetype)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                 id> *)options
     documentAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,
                                 id> * _Nullable *)docAttributes
                  error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

and it is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithURL:options:documentAttributes:error:) of apple documentation

Comment: Well, I was watching the wrong apple documentation page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your URLFile into NSData

```
NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLFILE];
```

Then use this method of NSAttributedString

```
initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:
```

May be this solution will help you.